# Qual método é acionado ao alterar um valor na classe PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android

Gostaria de capturar o campo alterado pelo usuário em uma classe que herda de PreferenceActivity.

Tentei sem sucesso sobrescrever: onContentChanged() e onActivityResult.

Comment: Herik, você quer escutar pela troca de valor de uma subclasse de `Preference` (dada sua instância), ou quer  escutar por qualquer trocar de valor (para qualquer `Preference`)? Você quer fazer por dentro da `PreferenceActivity` ou por fora?

Comment: Seria por dentro da minha atividade que herda de PreferenceActivity, neste caso quero pegar uma Preference especifica. Tal como definido no xml: <EditTextPreference 
            android:key="erp_cod_vendedor"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe `Preference`, assim como vários elementos do Android, possuem eventos.

No caso da classe `Preference`, ela tem dois ventos: [`OnPreferenceChange`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) e [`OnPreferenceClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html). Acredito que o primeiro seja o que você precisa.

Para ser notificado da mudança de valor de um `Preference`, você deve registrar um `OnPreferenceChangeListener` na preference desejada.

Para usar:

```
Preference p = findPreference("erp_cod_vendedor");

p.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
     public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
         // Valor mudou, faca algo
         return true; // Pode persistir o novo valor
     }
});
```